# Is it possible to include a .vssettings file in a .vsi

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vssettings, vsinstaller

In Visual Studio 2008, I've exported my settings to a .vssettings file.  I have a .vsi file that includes a .vscontent file.  In the .vscontent I've included a macro project like this:

```
...
<Content>
    <FileName>MyMacros.vsmacros</FileName>
    <DisplayName>MyMacros</DisplayName>
    <Description>MyMacros to aid development</Description>
    <FileContentType>Macro Project</FileContentType>
    <ContentVersion>2.0</ContentVersion>
</Content>
...
```

Is it possible to include a .vssettings file like this?  I can't seem to find the right FileContentType.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its possible (Hint Reflector+VSContentInstaller.exe)